# Writing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, merge

I think the algorithm would be Theta(mj) since we need to go through all m sorted lists each of which has size j.

Would it have to be iterative or recursive?

```
def mymerge(L1, L2,..., Lm):

    A = merge(L1,L2)
    return A + mymerge(L3,...., Lm)
```

Comment: Can you add what you've done even if it's wrong ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus This is what I have tried so far.

Comment: Tag your question with "algorithms" if you want the algo gurus to see your question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return mymerge(merge(L1, L2), L3 ... LM)`? And aren't you missing a base case? Like what if only one or two lists are given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both variants, either iterative or recursive. So, we have m lists and a function `merge` which merges two lists (no limitations given that the lists must have the same length).

Let's see an example with 4 lists `L1`, `L2`, `L3` and `L4` and extrapolate from there:

```
Intermediate1 = merge(L1, L2)
Intermediate2 = merge(Intermediate1, L3)
return merge(Intermediate2, L4)
```

We can write this in iterative form:

```
# It's a bit a mixture of Python and pseudo code,
# e.g. indexing is 1 based... loops are written as "1 to m"

# M is a list of m lists (so M = [L1, L2, ..., Lm])
def mymerge(M):
    m = len(M)

    intermediate = M[1]
    for i = 2 to m:
        intermediate = merge(intermediate, M[i])
    return intermediate
```

So, this is an iterative solution to the problem. However, we can also do it recursively.

For a recursive solution, we always need a base case and all other solutions will lead to the base case. In this case, our base case is that we get one list and just return it.

So let's start with the base case:

```
def mymerge(M):
    m = len(M)

    if m == 1:
        return M[1]
    else:
        TODO
```

Now, what happens if we have an `M` that has more lists than only one? In the case of two lists it is simple: We just call `merge(M[1], M[2])`. And in case of three or more lists? We need to take two lists, merge them together and then call `mymerge` again (with a list that gets one element shorter each recursion call, so we will end up in the base case of m = 1 at some point).

```
def mymerge(M):
    m = len(M)

    if m == 1:
        return M[1]
    else:
        # Copy all elements from M to M_new except for the last two
        # Combine the last two elements and append them to M_new
        M_new = M[1 to m-2] 
        M_new[m-1] = merge(M[m-1], M[m])
        return mymerge(M_new)
```

Comment: Would M represent a list of lists?

Comment: Exactly. Did not know how to represent an "index access" on the lists if I have `def mymerge(L1, L2, ..., Lm)`. `L_i` would look a bit unclear. If you have an idea, I will gladly change the function header, because for pseudo-code `def mymerge(L1, L2, ..., Lm)` is cleaner than `def mymerge(M)`.

Comment: In terms of pseudocode would L1,L2,...Lm be better than M in terms of proper format and clarity?

Comment: Also, any ideas on the theta bound?

Comment: Yep, I added an explanation (I left university a few years ago, so read it critically; might not be 100% correct notation).

Comment: "function merge which merges (and probably sorts)" there's no sorting. the merged list is already sorted, provided the two inputs were sorted lists (as it is indeed stated that they are).

Comment: You're right. I adjusted the answer and deleted the theta section, because it was mostly based on the assumption that `merge` is Theta(n log n).

Comment: @Aufziehvogel What would the theta bound be for the recursive algorithm you wrote.

Comment: @Aufziehvogel Please let me know.